# Query a Firestore document where a map key does not exist

Tags: firebase, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, document

I faced many limitations with Firestore:

1. cannot use multiple `not-in`
2. You can't combine `not-in` with `in`, `array-contains-any`, or `or` in the same query
3. every array filter can only check up to 10 values.

So I basically thought about changing data structure and use maps since they can be queried via `field.key`.

the key `field` of every document is not dynamic but each `key` of the map is.

this is an example of my structure:

```
// the collection
animals
  // the document (random id)
  dog
    // the field (a map value)
    food: {
      1: true
      2: true
      3: true
    }
```

The question the query should answer is:
"Give me every record where a specific value does not exist AND (other constraints)"

I am considering changing stack for this project because of this. Any good advice is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Firestore queries are based on a reference to the document being present in the index(es) used for the query.

If a document doesn't have a value for a certain field, it won't be present in an index on that field.

This implies that you can't query for documents that don't have a value for the field you want to query on.

Comment: In the past when I've run into these problems, I have made a point to explicitly define a field as an empty string or as `NULL` at the start so it's easy to query. When they get a defined value it's easy to update them.

Comment: Yup, that's indeed the solution: give every field a default value. That unfortunately also means you'll have to backfill all existing documents if you add a field to your data model later on.